# What is the conjugate transpose of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was trying to prove if the Hadamard gate matrix is unitary. Maybe you can help me out in figuring out the conjugate tranpose of this matrix: 
$\frac{1}{\surd2} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$

**My thoughts so far**
I suspect that the conjugate transpose is
$\frac{1}{\surd2} \begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1 \\-1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. If this is right, then multiplying this adjoint to the actual matrix, will result in this matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. Is this the same as the identity matrix?

Comment: Your guess is very bizarre. Do you know what the words "conjugate" and "transpose" mean separately in this context?

Comment: I heard two conflicting methods to go about calculating the conjugate. One is to just flip the signs of the imaginary part of the vector, which would result in the same matrix. The other was from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHzpMgKuI9Q&t=117s I used the method from this video

Comment: Since the matrix is symmetrical I think that my error lies in finding the conjugate instead of the transposing part.

Comment: That video doesn't seem to have anything to do with complex conjugation.

Comment: I thought that this doesn't have to do with complex numbers either. Forgive me, I'm new to linear algebra. I thought that this is a real matrix so that complex conjugation isn't needed.

Comment: You just take the transpose and then conjugate each entry. The matrix is symmetric, like you said, so taking the transpose doesn't "do anything." To take the conjugate, you change the sign of the imaginary part. (*Is* there an imaginary part?)

Comment: No there isn't, so is the conjugate transpose equal to the starting matrix?

Comment: @Sinestro38 The video you linked is about the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), which is also known as the "adjoint" is some contexts. This has nothing to do with the conjugate transpose. Unfortunately, the term "adjoint" is also (and in fact mostly) used to refer to the conjugate-transpose of a matrix.

Comment: @Sinestro38 And yes: in this case, the conjugate-transpose is equal to the starting matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matrix is symmetric and all of its entries are real, so it's equal to its conjugate transpose.

The matrix you are asking about is different from the identity matrix.

But the original matrix *is* unitary.